# How to perform function after file upload in admin page..?

Tags: python, django

My `data_report` function just parse the xml file and save those value into database that is it. But requirement is admin only can upload the `excel` file.

So the question is ...

1. if admin can upload file to server  how can i process the file ?.. ( after
   save .. ?)
2. Admin url`http://localhost.com:8000/admin/reports/` can redirect to the function page..?

Below the code use for admin/reports

```
def get_admin_urls(urls):
    def get_urls():
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^reports/$', admin.site.admin_view(data_report))
        )
       return my_urls + urls
    return get_urls

admin_urls = get_admin_urls(admin.site.get_urls())
admin.site.get_urls = admin_urls
```

Again question is ...

- how to add link in admin app page ..
- i don't know how to redirect to admin page after file upload..?

but you know what the link is working but i can't access no other admin page here the error is

```
Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': u'default'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'admin/(?P<app_label>auth|dsp|sites)/$']
```

Can help me solve this problem ..?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, `uploading` means in your case, select a file and hit the `save` button in admin, right?

in that case, you can override the save method of this model which then should parse and save into other models or into itself etc etc

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

  def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
      xmlfile = form.cleaned_data['your_xmlfile_fieldname'] 
      # parse and stuff
      obj.save()
```

Comment: So you are saying that no need write `data_report` function in views.py ..?

Comment: just parse xml in models.py itself and call the db and and save ... is that it ?

Comment: @HelloWorld yes, but make sure this is not a normal model class, this is modeladmin class which sits in admin.py look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Comment: seems lot of error here ..  tell me how to get the file path ? or inserted ID ..?

Comment: ok i am getting the id using obj.id but `foranalyse = Reports.objects.get(pk=obj.id)` ... give me error only obj not define

Comment: @HelloWorld ``obj`` is model instance and ``form`` is the form data coming from admin fields.